# Can 'pretend' be used as an adjective?

Tags: word-usage

When my daughter played with her friends in our house, they used an IKEA laundry hamper and a few blankets to build a "pretend pirate cave", as they mentioned.

So far as I know 'pretend' is a verb.  But in this case, sounds to me it was used as an adjective.  Is that a legitimate usage?

Thanks.

Comment: It is a very common colloquial use, particularly among children and those who interact with children. It should not be emulated in formal writing except for ironic effect.

Comment: One of the interesting things about English is that because it's so weakly inflected, it's easy to use words as other parts of speech - to use a verb like an adjective, or a noun like a verb, or a verb like a noun, etc. - and this is a very good example of that.

Answer (score 2):

You are right about pretend being a verb but it can also act as an adjective (informal) like in 'pretend pirate cave'. 
When such verbs act as adjectives they are called '**attributive verbs**', as they modify the noun.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  "Pretend friends" is a very common way to describe a child's imaginary playmates ("imaginary" is another way, of course).

But be cautious, "pretend friend" can also mean "false friend", depending on how said.

Comment: Please let me know, if you don't mind, when you say false friend, you mean in the [grammatical sense](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend), or in real life?

Comment: Oh, sorry, Lucian, I should have thought of that:  real life, someone pretending to be a friend who isn't.

Comment: @LucianSava In that case, it would probably be _false friends_ because it is referred to two words in two different language.